# Getting Python errors whenever I try to use terminal in Linux Mint

Tags: bash, linux-mint, terminal, python

I've had Mint installed as a dual boot on my laptop for some time. I use it as my dev environment, for desktop and web related coding.
I recently started getting errors which have rendered my terminal unusable. As soon as I start the program up I get the error

```
/usr/bin/env: bash: No such file or directory
```

Whenever I try to run a command, I then get the following output:

```
brae@G62-Linux ~ $ ifconfig
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/command-not-found", line 21, in <module>
os.execvp("python3", [sys.argv[0]] + sys.argv)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 344, in execvp
_execvpe(file, args)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 380, in _execvpe
func(fullname, *argrest)
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I don't want to start screwing around with files I don't fully understand, and most of the standard things (apt-get update etc.) aren't possible because of the errors. Can anyone give me any advice? I would just blank the partition and reinstall but I really can't be bothered going through all of that if I don't need to.

Thanks very much.

==========================================================

EDIT- SOLUTION

Thanks to the best answer below, I tracked down the problem to my .bashrc file. Turns out something had modified the file to alter the PATH variable with a Ruby environment which was causing the error. I simply deleted this section from the file (in my case this left the .bashrc file empty) and this solved the error. I believe that if this leaves the file blank, you can also change the .bash_profile (or .profile) file to no longer call the .bashrc file as it is not a requirement for the process.

Thanks for you help everyone who answered, particularly apaul

Comment: From the first error, I'd guess your machine can't find the `bash` executable. What does `which bash` print? The rest of it sounds pretty confusing, since `ifconfig` doesn't really have anything to do with Python. What terminal program is this? (It might be good to edit the question with the details.)

Comment: The second error is from the `command-not-found` program, which searches for packages containing a command. I'm going to guess your PATH is messed up. What is the output of `echo $PATH`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many possibilities. At login time, usually, 3 steps are done:

1) At login time, the shell specified in `/etc/passwd` is launched. So I'd first have a look at `/etc/passwd` (using GUI as `gedit`, since you can't use terminal...) and check the shell (it's the last field). You may have a line like this for your user:

```
user:x:500:500::/home/user:/bin/bash
```

(You may have `/bin/sh`, `/bin/csh`, `/bin/zsh`, ... but `/bin/bash` is the most common)

2) Then the shell will read the content of your `/home/user/.bash_profile` (if you use `bash`). So I'd look this file (ie: open it with `gedit`, but watch out, filenames starting with a `.` are hidden by default) and see if it launch any python command.

3) Finally, `/home/user/.bashrc` is also read when launching your terminal. So I'd have a look at this file too.

These are the first steps I'd do, looking if any of these files launch a `python`, `ipython`, `xonsh` command, or any py script.

Comment: If `bash` is not found, and `/etc/passwd` sets `bash` as user's shell, then none of the steps you suggest - that rely on the shell (i.e., most) will work.

Comment: @boardrider Yep, that's why I ask him to use a GUI to read these 3 files. But yeah, my text is not clear, I'll edit it.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Been trying to find time to sit down and have a proper go at this since then.

I can't see any sign of anything out of the ordinary in these files. The only thing I did notice was actually the line you mentioned

    user:x:500:500::/home/user:/bin/bash

The numbers are not 500, 500. What does this affect?

Comment: @GeneralBrae No, these are ID for your user and his group. It doesn't affect.